# How to get a Symfony 2 configuration inside a Doctrine entity?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've a simple Doctrine Entity in which I have to handle file uploads. I've followed the Symfony recomendations to implement this entity (cf. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html), so I have an entity which look like this (simplified):

```
<?php
// src/Acme/DemoBundle/Entity/Document.php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Document
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    public $name;

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
    {
        // the absolute directory path where uploaded
        // documents should be saved
        return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
    }

    protected function getUploadDir()
    {
        // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
        // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
        return 'uploads/documents';
    }
}
```

I would like to go a step further by making the upload dir configurable in a Symfony config file, like this:

```
parameters:
    upload_dir: new_upload_dir_value
```

And then use this configuration value in my entity, instead of:

- guessing the upload dir based on the current file in `getUploadRootDir` method (what would happen if I change the Entity file location ?)
- putting the `"uploads"` string directly in the `getUploadDir` method (I would like to be able to change it's name whenever I want)

I'm new to Symfony2 so maybe I don't have the right approach to handle this case, but does anyone know a good way to handle this without too many drawbacks ?

Comment: Entities are not the place meant where to store those settings. You should create your own class that handles file uploads, registered as a service in the DIC, which will accept upload_dir parameter.

Comment: Yes, I agree with Stefano. Although, I did make this mistake during the first few month of Symfony2 and it was horrible experience :(

Comment: Ok I got it, but why does the official documentation says to do so then ? Too bad :(

Comment: Just take a look at [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) - you'll love it :)